# How to execute a Rails "Rake Task"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rake, task

what's up?

My friend created a rake task to update our data in the database (because we have db changes). **Following is the task:**

```
namespace :db do

  task :update_database => :environment do
    puts "Update do banco"

    posts = Post.where("source_id is null").order("id")
    done = Array.new
    posts.each do |post|
      if post.source_id.nil? and !done.include?(post)
        posts2 = Post.where("content LIKE ? AND id != ?", post.content, post.id)
        done.concat(posts2)
        posts2.each do |post2|
          post2.source_id = post.id
          post2.save
        end
      end
    end

  end
end
```

I already executed this rake task in my localhost, but I deploy my project to heroku and now my project won't open online. I don't remember what's the command to execute rake tasks and I can't find it in no place.

**My questions is:**

1. What's the command to execute rake tasks?
2. What's the command to execute rake tasks on heroku? Just "heroku run "?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
heroku run bundle exec rake db:update_database
```

should do.

`bundle exec` ensures that the script is run in the context of current bundle.